# Excel VBA paste a wrap text in one cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste, paste

I've tried in a lot of different ways but i can't find out a solution, I'm going mad!
my problem is that I have a cell that contains a sequence of command written in HTML and I want to write them ALL IN ONE CELL in normal text and that even the wrap test stay in that cell and not in a different row.

Just to be more understandable:

Now I obtain this:
[As you can see here all is in different row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WeU6.jpg)

What I want is this:[Everithing is in the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99qw.jpg)

```
Sub TRY_HTML_TEXT()
Dim Ie As Object
Dim text As String
'First part is made to convert from HTML to Text

Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With Ie

    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value
         'update to the cell that contains HTML you want converted
    .ExecWB 17, 0
         'Select all contents in browser
    .ExecWB 12, 2
         'Copy them

    Sheet1.Select
    'Select my sheet
    Range("M3").Select
    'selection of the cell where i want to copy
    SendKeys "{F2}"
    'I've selected inside the cell to have the possibility to paste enter code here
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Paste what i have
   .Quit

End With
Set Ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you can help me, many thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Do not Select the Whole Sheet. Select the Cell you have wanted to put on your value then paste it. You are referring to the whole Sheet.

Use ActiveCell. Not Sheet.

`ActiveCell.PasteSpecial`

Regards,

Comment: How'd you do it?

Comment: Removed all the references to the sheet
    .document.body.InnerHTML = Range("G3").Value
    'Sheet1.Select
and also change ActiveCell.PasteSpecial